# network-switch where I can allow which ports can communicate with each other

Tags: switch

I'm searching a switch where I can route all ethernet packages over one input/output port. It should be impossible to communicate directly between two ports, but with that single on.
How is such a feature, where I can decide which ports are allowed to communicate directly with eachother, called?

Comment: You are not very clear on what you are asking. Do you mean somethng like Private VLANs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this depending on the switch vendor.
Here is a list of features that can accomplish what you want to do:

- Private VLANs
- EVC: Ethernet Virtual Connection
- VPC: Virtual Private Connection
- Bridge ports

The list goes on, but that should be a good starting point to compare switches with.